# TagHelper not working properly even though registered in the viewimports

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Even though i have registered my tag helper as such in the following way its not being found under the Html helper. Once I do @Html. it should appear but its not is it like sql intellence needs reloaded in some how?

```
_ViewImports
```

As per below

```
@using MISSystem.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using SharedResourceLib.Lng;

@inject ISharedResource SharedResource
@addTagHelper *, Localization.AspNetCore.TagHelpers
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@addTagHelper *, LazZiya.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *,MISSystem.Web.Helpers
@addTagHelper *,MISSystem.Web

@using static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage;
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using System.Security.Claims
```

This is my helper method

```
namespace MISSystem.Web.Helpers {
public static class GravatarHelper {
    public static HtmlString GravatarImage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string emailAddress, GravatarOptions options = null) {
        if (options == null)
            options = GravatarOptions.GetDefaults();

        var imgTag = new TagBuilder("img");

        emailAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress) ? string.Empty : emailAddress.Trim().ToLower();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(options.CssClass)) {
            imgTag.AddCssClass(options.CssClass);
        }

        imgTag.Attributes.Add("src", string.Format("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?s={1}{2}{3}",
                GetMd5Hash(emailAddress),
                options.Size,
                "&d=" + options.DefaultImageType,
                "&r=" + options.RatingLevel
            )
        );

        return new HtmlString(imgTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
    }

    // Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5.aspx
    private static string GetMd5Hash(string input) {
        byte[] data = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));
        var sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++) {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

And this is how I am trying to user the helper

```
@Html.GravatarHelper(User.Identity.GetUserName();, new GravatarOptions { Size = 30, CssClass = "img-circle" })
```

The error I am facing is

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS1061  'IHtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for
> 'GravatarHelper' and no accessible extension method 'GravatarHelper'
> accepting a first argument of type 'IHtmlHelper' could be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)   MISSystem.Web   Views\Shared_AdminLteLayout.cshtml 104 Active

Comment: This was a valid quesiton why its been down voted twice is beyond me

Answer (score 0):

What i need to do was change my method signature as follows. Once I done this the tag helper was discoverable

```
public static IHtmlContent GravatarImage(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string emailAddress, GravatarOptions options = null)
```